# AUDIO PROBLEMS: Sound Stopped Working After Reboot!

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 15.10, pulseaudio, alsa

As the title says, my sound has stopped working after a reboot. This is a new system (one-week old hardware, fresh install of Kubuntu 15.10). Linux audio is quite complicated, and I've tried my best to search forums and troubleshoot, but to no avail. Currently, Phonon Audio and Video can't detect any of my hardware devices and drivers, just lists a "Dummy Output". My backend is Phonon GStreamer.

This is what I've done so far to try to solve this problem.

1. Installed all recent updates.
2. Checked if my sound card is found by Kubuntu:

   ```
   $ aplay -l
   aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
   ```
3. Checked if my sound card is detected by Kubuntu/ALSA:

   ```
   $ echo "Sound cards recognized by the system:"; lspci -nn | grep --color=none '\[04[80][13]\]'; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel modules: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel drivers in use: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done
   Sound cards recognized by the system:
   00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
   Sound cards recognized by ALSA:
   00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
   Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:
   00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
   ```
4. Checked if my sound card is enabled:

   ```
   $ lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' 
   00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
   ```

   Longer output:

   ```
   00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
     Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86c7
     Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
     Status: 
     Latency: 32
     Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 126
     Region 0: Memory at d1040000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
     Region 4: Memory at d1020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]           Capabilities: 
     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
   ```

   I also made sure in my BIOS that the sound card is enabled.
5. Removed, purged and reinstalled `alsa-base`, `alsa-utils`, `pulseaudio`, `linux-sound-base`.
6. Upgraded to latest ALSA-drivers (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) ... currently have the package `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201603112217~ubuntu15.10.1_all.deb` installed.
7. Added myself to the proper groups:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
   ```

None of this so far has worked! Here's my asla-info (http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1ae266957dabeba501ddfea2ba68f9b1fd99f304).

I appreciate all of you in helping me out with this problem.

Comment: I think you should not have to be adding yourself to groups manually these days to get sound working. My suggestion might seem more extreme but .... try Kubuntu 14.04 or Mint KDE 17.3. I suspect it "might" be a 15.10 issue. I know that is a rather lame answer but with sound in Linux, life is too short :-)

Comment: Today I rebooted to find myself with the exact same problem: same sound card as this post, same system, and same symptomps: dummy output and alsa lists no sound cards. Any help will be much appreciated.

This is not the first time I have this problem with Kubuntu 15.10, but last time I had a pretty old installation (upgraded throughout the years). and reinstalling from scratch earlier in 2016 made the problem disappear. Now the issue is here again but on a fairly fresh install.

Comment: Hmm, I played around a little and noticed that if I run sudo aplay -l the sound cards are listed correctly. Perhaps it is some sort of a permission issue? @dickson -wong, do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, `sudo aplay -l` gave me the same output as before: `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`